# WCF Requests Timeout On Large Binary Calls

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a thin WCF client which is calling a WCF service. The WCF performs well until large binary transfers are needed...then the calls appear to stack up and then timeout. The app is dead until the appPool is recycled.

Here are the settings:

SERVER:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding 
name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" 
maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
<readerQuotas 
maxDepth="32" 
maxStringContentLength="5242880" 
maxArrayLength="1073741824" 
maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" 
maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
<security mode="Message">
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
</security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

CLIENT:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding 
name="WebServices" 
closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
openTimeout="00:01:00" 
receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
transactionFlow="false" 
hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="123487960" maxArrayLength="12621440" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
<reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
<security mode="Message">
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
</transport>
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
</security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

The obvious problem, a logjam in retrieving the binary content from the database, does not appear to be the case. The strong appearance is that something is stacking up and not getting released.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the timeouts on the server as well?

I suspect that the server may be timing out as the default timeouts are relatively low (1 minute, I believe). The timeouts specified in the client config only apply to the client, not the server.

Comment: I've considered setting the timeout higher, but that sure seems like it would just be masking the problem. This call should be completing in subsecond times...I think it has more to do with the transport of the data.

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens - are you using TransferMode.Buffered or TransferMode.Streaming? If it's buffered, could that be the problem maybe?

Comment: I think the default for this binding is Buffered, so that could be part of the problem. I tried adding the attribute to the binding with a value of Streaming, but that didn't work...it does not appear that this binding type of wsHttpBinding accepts that parameter.

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens - you're right, it won't work with wsHttpBinding.  Here's an article that might help - [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)